# Proof-verification: A level set not being a regular submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-verification, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I wish to show, using elementary techniques, that if $f(x)=-x_1^2-x_2^2-...-x_\theta^2+x_{\theta+1}^2+...+x_n^2$ is a map from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R$, then $f^{-1}(0)$ is not a regular submanifold of $\mathbb R^n$.

Toward a solution, I know that $f$ in any neighborhood of 0 does not have constant rank. But it is not enough to give me any clue, since I must prove that no chart $(U,\psi)$ on $\mathbb R^n$ with $0\in U$ satisfies the regular submanifold property. How must I proceed?

Appendix: According to the comments below, I realized that it seems easier to prove that it is not a manifold in its own right. Deleting zero from any neighborhood of zero in $f^{-1}(0)$ turns it into a nonconnected subset so that no neighborhood of zero in $f^{-1}(0)$ is not homeomorphic to any open set of Euclidean space. Is it correct?

Comment: Did you try some simple case, like $\theta = 1$ and $n=2$?

Comment: I think in that case we get two mutually perpendicular lines, which is seemingly not a manifold. But it does not explicitly make use of the definition of regular submanifold @JohnMa

Comment: A union of two perpendicular lines is not a regular submanifold. That's true but how do you prove that?

Comment: I think that the intersection of any neighborhood of the joint of the lines with the lines themselves is not homeomorphic to any open set, but if $\theta$ is not one and $n$ is not two, how must I generalize? @JohnMa

Comment: I added a solution based on these observations to my post @JohnMa